# A surprising tag from Stanford-POS-Tagger

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I used `Stanford-POS-Tagger` on the following text (from a *Times of India News Report* on the player-auctions under Indian Premier League):

> Royal Challengers Bangalore are used to making strong statements at
>   the Indian Premier League auctions and they did so again on Saturday
>   (February 6) with the marquee signing of seasoned Australian
>   all-rounder Shane Watson. The staggering Rs 9.5 crore that the team
>   paid for the 34-year-old made him the costliest buy this year.
>
> The Vijay Mallya-owned side fought off stiff competition from new
>   entrants Rising Pune Supergiants and defending champions Mumbai
>   Indians to snare the former Rajasthan Royals star. Watson, a battling
>   right-handed batsman and handy medium-pacer, will add serious bite to
>   the Virat Kohli-led Bengaluru side still chasing their maiden title.

For the last sentence, in the II-para, the `Stanford-POS-Tagger` tagged the first word `'Watson'` as a base verb! I searched `Chambers' Twentieth Century Dictionary` to see if the word `'watson'` is a verb, but I could locate no such entry!

I got the following output from some functions I have ran in my code:

> Watson,VB aDT battlingVBG rightJJ handedNN batsmanNN andCC handyJJ
>   mediumNN pacer,NN willMD addVB seriousJJ biteNN toTO theDT ViratNNP
>   KohliNNP ledVBD BengaluruNNP sideNN stillRB chasingVBG theirPRP$
>   maidenJJ title.NN

Comment: Which version of Stanford POS Tagger are you using? Are you using it directly with the Java code? Or through the bash or through other API?

Comment: I got the same results with both v3.5.2 and v3.6.0. Pl see my other comments below, on what is / may be happening.

Comment: Can you paste your output in the question? So that we compare the difference, i think you haven't sentence tokenized your paragaph before sending it to the POS tagger.

Comment: @alvas Yes, I did tokenize the text into sentences and called the Tagger for each sentence in turn. I suggest you run the tagger with my referred-sentence as the only sentence or as the first sentence in the chunk of text.

Comment: Can you please paste your  output to the example you gave? Otherwise it's rather hard to know what went wrong. We can show our outputs but without looking at yours, it's quite impossible to know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @alvas I have called the Tagger-API from within my code; so I cannot provide the output similar to what you may have from the Tagger-GUI. Here is my output for the referred sentence: Watson,VB 
 aDT 
 battlingVBG 
 rightJJ 
 handedNN 
 batsmanNN 
 andCC 
 handyJJ 
 mediumNN 
 pacer,NN 
 willMD 
 addVB 
 seriousJJ 
 biteNN 
 toTO 
 theDT 
 ViratNNP 
 KohliNNP 
 ledVBD 
 BengaluruNNP 
 sideNN 
 stillRB 
 chasingVBG 
 theirPRP$ 
 maidenJJ 
 title.NN

Comment: Please spend some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask otherwise people will close your valid questions easily on stackoverflow.

Comment: The information that you call the tagger from your own code via the API, rather than from the command line, plus that the comma has not been separated would have allowed experts to see straight away that the problem is in how you call the API.

Comment: @SatyanarayanaKrishnamurthy BTW, your output clearly shows that you haven't tokenized your text before POS tagging =)

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that you have not tokenized your text before POS tagging.

As @ChristopherManning showed, the output of the Stanford POS tagger will be correct if you tokenized your text before you tag.

Using the `CoreNLP` on command line:

```
alvas@ubi:~/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ echo """Royal Challengers Bangalore are used to making strong statements at the Indian Premier League auctions and they did so again on Saturday (February 6) with the marquee signing of seasoned Australian all-rounder Shane Watson. The staggering Rs 9.5 crore that the team paid for the 34-year-old made him the costliest buy this year.

The Vijay Mallya-owned side fought off stiff competition from new entrants Rising Pune Supergiants and defending champions Mumbai Indians to snare the former Rajasthan Royals star. Watson, a battling right-handed batsman and handy medium-pacer, will add serious bite to the Virat Kohli-led Bengaluru side still chasing their maiden title.""" > watson.txt
alvas@ubi:~/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ 
alvas@ubi:~/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos -outputFormat json -file watson.txt
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.6 sec].

Processing file /home/alvas/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/watson.txt ... writing to /home/alvas/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/watson.txt.json
Annotating file /home/alvas/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/watson.txt
done.
Annotation pipeline timing information:
TokenizerAnnotator: 0.1 sec.
WordsToSentencesAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
POSTaggerAnnotator: 0.1 sec.
TOTAL: 0.1 sec. for 110 tokens at 791.4 tokens/sec.
Pipeline setup: 1.6 sec.
Total time for StanfordCoreNLP pipeline: 1.9 sec
```

The output will be saved in `watson.txt.json` and with some munging:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('watson.txt.json') as fin:
...     output = json.load(fin)
... 
>>> for sent in output['sentences']:
...     print ' '.join([tok['word']+'/'+tok['pos'] for tok in sent['tokens']]) + '\n'
... 

Royal/NNP Challengers/NNS Bangalore/NNP are/VBP used/VBN to/TO making/VBG strong/JJ statements/NNS at/IN the/DT Indian/JJ Premier/NNP League/NNP auctions/NNS and/CC they/PRP did/VBD so/RB again/RB on/IN Saturday/NNP -LRB-/-LRB- February/NNP 6/CD -RRB-/-RRB- with/IN the/DT marquee/JJ 

signing/NN of/IN seasoned/JJ Australian/JJ all-rounder/NN Shane/NNP Watson/NNP ./.

The/DT staggering/JJ Rs/NN 9.5/CD crore/VBP that/IN the/DT team/NN paid/VBN for/IN the/DT 34-year-old/JJ made/VBD him/PRP the/DT costliest/JJS buy/VB this/DT year/NN ./.

The/DT Vijay/NNP Mallya-owned/JJ side/NN fought/VBD off/RP stiff/JJ competition/NN from/IN new/JJ entrants/NNS Rising/VBG Pune/NNP Supergiants/NNPS and/CC defending/VBG champions/NNS Mumbai/NNP Indians/NNPS to/TO snare/VB the/DT former/JJ Rajasthan/NNP Royals/NNPS star/NN ./.

Watson/NNP ,/, a/DT battling/VBG right-handed/JJ batsman/NN and/CC handy/JJ medium-pacer/NN ,/, will/MD add/VB serious/JJ bite/NN to/TO the/DT Virat/NNP Kohli-led/NNP Bengaluru/NNP side/NN still/RB chasing/VBG their/PRP$ maiden/JJ title/NN ./.
```

Note that if you're using the Stanford CoreNLP on command line it will **NOT** allow you to POS tag without tokenization:

```
alvas@ubi:~/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators pos -outputFormat json -file watson.txt[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.4 sec].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "pos" requires annotator "tokenize"
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:139)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:135)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1214)
```

Regardless of whether you're using Stanford POS tagger through the GUI, command-line, a python API or directly through importing the library in your Java code, it is advisable to sentence tokenize your text, then word tokenize each sentence before POS tagging them.

The Stanford CoreNLP API provides an example of how you can annotate your data in Java: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce this tagging with either the default model using the current version (3.6.0) or the slower, better model.... (But in general, the tagger isn't limited to a dictionary of taggings and can choose the tag it thinks most appropriate in context.)

```
$ java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger -textFile watson.txt 

Loading default properties from tagger edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger

Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.7 sec].

Royal_NNP Challengers_NNS Bangalore_NNP are_VBP used_VBN to_TO making_VBG strong_JJ statements_NNS at_IN the_DT Indian_JJ Premier_NNP League_NNP auctions_NNS and_CC they_PRP did_VBD so_RB again_RB on_IN Saturday_NNP -LRB-_-LRB- February_NNP 6_CD -RRB-_-RRB- with_IN the_DT marquee_JJ signing_NN of_IN seasoned_JJ Australian_JJ all-rounder_NN Shane_NNP Watson_NNP ._.
The_DT staggering_JJ Rs_NN 9.5_CD crore_VBP that_IN the_DT team_NN paid_VBN for_IN the_DT 34-year-old_JJ made_VBD him_PRP the_DT costliest_JJS buy_VB this_DT year_NN ._.
The_DT Vijay_NNP Mallya-owned_JJ side_NN fought_VBD off_RP stiff_JJ competition_NN from_IN new_JJ entrants_NNS Rising_VBG Pune_NNP Supergiants_NNPS and_CC defending_VBG champions_NNS Mumbai_NNP Indians_NNPS to_TO snare_VB the_DT former_JJ Rajasthan_NNP Royals_NNPS star_NN ._.
Watson_NNP ,_, a_DT battling_VBG right-handed_JJ batsman_NN and_CC handy_JJ medium-pacer_NN ,_, will_MD add_VB serious_JJ bite_NN to_TO the_DT Virat_NNP Kohli-led_NNP Bengaluru_NNP side_NN still_RB chasing_VBG their_PRP$ maiden_JJ title_NN ._.

Tagged 110 words at 859.38 words per second.
```

Comment: I have been using v3.5.2 - I will try with v3.6.0 and confirm. Also, that version (3.5.2)  tagged "battling" as VBG instead of Present-Participle; 3.6.0 seems to do the same thing. The Tag-set does not seem to have Present-Participle at all. Is this a gap or a conscious omission?

Comment: Tried with v3.6.0 - still getting VB for "Watson" in the referred sentence.

Comment: Further, in the referred sentence, the word "led" is really a past participle, but is not recognized as such. In my code, I do a de-hyphen operation before calling the Tagger and "led" is tagged as "VBD".

Comment: I have a hunch as to what is going on: I am breaking up the chunk-of-text into sentences and invoking the Tagger on each sentence, in turn. Could this be the reason? Is it necessary to pass the entire chink of text to the Tagger for avoiding such error? If that is the situation, consider a use case where utterances exchanged in a live-chat are passed by the chat-bot to the Tagger - here only single sentences may be available at certain points in time. Is there a case for the Tagger to build and maintain the discourse-context?

Comment: The word "Watson," (with a comma at the end) has been tagged as VB, The Training-Model used does not adequately recognize the importance of the comma as a syntax-element in English. English uses the comma for multiple purposes - eg. as a mark-up for suppressed-conjunction, as in the referred sentence (it is like: "Watson who is a battling right-handed batsman ...."). I reckon  the tagger is treating the sentence as a command (without a subject), with "a battling right-handed batsman ..." as the object for "watson" as a verb. But can a comma appear between a verb and its object?

Comment: Refer last cmnt on comma as syntax-element for suppressed-conjunction: Tagger-output for the sentence with explicit-conjunction ("Watson who is a battling right-handed batsman and handy medium-pacer, will add serious bite to the Virat Kohli-led Bengaluru side still chasing their maiden title.": WatsonNNP 
 whoWP 
 isVBZ 
 aDT 
 battlingVBG 
 rightJJ 
 handedNN 
 batsmanNN 
 andCC 
 handyJJ 
 mediumNN 
 pacer,NN 
 willMD 
 addVB 
 seriousJJ 
 biteNN 
 toTO 
 theDT 
 ViratNNP 
 KohliNNP 
 ledVBD 
 BengaluruNNP 
 sideNN 
 stillRB 
 chasingVBG 
 theirPRP$ 
 maidenJJ 
 title.

Comment: No, that's not it. I reduced "watson.txt" in the above command to just the last sentence and "Watson" is still tagged as a noun. Also also checked whether providing tokenised input confuses the tagger but that's also fine.

Comment: OK, I was not aware that a word with comma needs to be split into two tokens for proper results from the Tagger. I have implemented, in my parser, comma-related logic (like lists of nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs, lists of complex clauses, etc) which depends on the comma being in place with the word, so I will look to recast that implementation and then I should be doing OK in using the Tagger.

Comment: For the sentence "Watson, who is a battling right-handed batsman and handy medium-pacer, will add serious bite to the Virat Kohli-led Bengaluru side still chasing their maiden title.", where the comma in "Watson," is not tokenized, I am getting the output: Watson,NNP 
 whoWP 
 isVBZ 
 aDT 
 battlingVBG 
 rightJJ 
 handedNN 
 batsmanNN 
 andCC 
 handyJJ 
 mediumNN 
 pacer,NN 
 willMD 
 addVB 
 seriousJJ 
 biteNN 
 toTO 
 theDT 
 ViratNNP 
 KohliNNP 
 ledVBD 
 BengaluruNNP 
 sideNN 
 stillRB 
 chasingVBG 
 theirPRP$ 
 maidenJJ 
 title.NN - so, tokenizing the comma is not so critical or decisive.

Comment: @Christopher Here is the essential code: 
     String[] sentWords; //duly initialized,populated
     MaxentTagger mTagger = new MaxentTagger( "./stanford-postagger/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
     List<HasWord> hWordList = Sentence.toWordList(sentWords);
     List<TaggedWord> tWordList = mTagger.tagSentence(hWordList);
     if (tWordList != null && !tWordList.isEmpty()){       
        for(TaggedWord tWord : tWordList){
         if (tWord != null){
          String theTag = tWord.tag();
          //print the tag, do further needed processing
         }
        }
     }

Comment: Yes, the tokenizer is designed to work on text tokenized according to Penn Treebank conventions (for English; other conventions for other languages). You can either have it tokenize as it works, e.g., using the `String tagString(String toTag)` method or you can give it tokenized text. If the text is tokenized badly - such as on whitespace - results will go downhill. Each sentence is tagged independently, so you should get the same results whether you give it a whole text or a sentence at a time. VBG is the correct tag for present participle. VBD for *led* is wrong, but an easy error to make.

Answer (score 0):

using maven packages I can't replicate this behavior. Make sure you are using the correct tagger. I am using the default one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
   <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency> 

public void test(){
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(MaxentTagger.DEFAULT_JAR_PATH);
    String test = "Royal Challengers Bangalore are used to making strong statements at the Indian Premier League auctions and they did so again on Saturday (February 6) with the marquee signing of seasoned Australian all-rounder Shane Watson. The staggering Rs 9.5 crore that the team paid for the 34-year-old made him the costliest buy this year.The Vijay Mallya-owned side fought off stiff competition from new entrants Rising Pune Supergiants and defending champions Mumbai Indians to snare the former Rajasthan Royals star. Watson, a battling right-handed batsman and handy medium-pacer, will add serious bite to the Virat Kohli-led Bengaluru side still chasing their maiden title.";
    String taggedString = tagger.tagString(test);
    System.out.println(taggedString);
}
```

This code returns

`Royal_NNP Challengers_NNS Bangalore_NNP are_VBP used_VBN to_TO making_VBG strong_JJ statements_NNS at_IN the_DT Indian_JJ Premier_NNP League_NNP auctions_NNS and_CC they_PRP did_VBD so_RB again_RB on_IN Saturday_NNP -LRB-_-LRB- February_NNP 6_CD -RRB-_-RRB- with_IN the_DT marquee_JJ signing_NN of_IN seasoned_JJ Australian_JJ all-rounder_NN Shane_NNP Watson_NNP ._. The_DT staggering_JJ Rs_NN 9.5_CD crore_VBP that_IN the_DT team_NN paid_VBN for_IN the_DT 34-year-old_JJ made_VBD him_PRP the_DT costliest_JJS buy_VB this_DT year.The_NNP Vijay_NNP Mallya-owned_JJ side_NN fought_VBD off_RP stiff_JJ competition_NN from_IN new_JJ entrants_NNS Rising_VBG Pune_NNP Supergiants_NNPS and_CC defending_VBG champions_NNS Mumbai_NNP Indians_NNPS to_TO snare_VB the_DT former_JJ Rajasthan_NNP Royals_NNPS star_NN ._. Watson_NNP ,_, a_DT battling_VBG right-handed_JJ batsman_NN and_CC handy_JJ medium-pacer_NN ,_, will_MD add_VB serious_JJ bite_NN to_TO the_DT Virat_NNP Kohli-led_NNP Bengaluru_NNP side_NN still_RB chasing_VBG their_PRP$ maiden_JJ title_NN ._.`